# how to update reference relationship in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have a mongoose schema of doctor as

```
{
   doctorname:"",
   age:"",
   rating:[{patientid:"",
           rating:""
           }]
 }
```

i want to update rating given by different patient to the doctor.
if the same patient is given rating to one particular doctor then it should be updated. else if different patient are giving rating then it should  be inserted as

```
rating:[{
        patientid:"",
        rating:""
        },
        {
        patientid:"",
        rating:""
        }]
```

i am having problem since its being updated every time. any kind of help will be appriciated.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) and [plugins](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/plugins.html). You will have to construct pre-save hook, which will recalculate the doctor's rating.

Also, you can use [instance methods](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) and implement something like this:

```
doctorInstance.rate(patientInstance, rating)
```